# CouchDB/PouchDB User Authentication/Authorization

Tags: ios, facebook, angularjs, couchdb, iriscouch

I have been working on an Angular/Ionic application and am using the OAuth.io plugin to handle a facebook login to gain a user's information.  From that I derive a simple database name based on the user's firstname and their Facebook ID number.

What I am wanting to do would be to sync this local pouchDB instance to an online CouchDB instance (currently using http://iriscouch.com) for replication to a desktop app, or something similar.  The piece I am missing is how to handle user authentication/authorization to be able to only read and write to their own database and no one else's as all of the code currently lives on the client side with no app server to handle any login aside from the OAuth.io plugin.

Is this possible to handle without adding an app server layer, and without manual intervention to create a user on the CouchDB instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can only do per-user read-write permissions in CouchDB by having an additional process on the server side ([details](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#some-people-can-read-some-docs-some-people-can-write-those-same-docs)), which would be troublesome for you since you're using IrisCouch, so you'd need a separate server somewhere to host this process.

A few alternative options are available to you right now:

- Couchbase, which has per-user databases
- [Janus](https://github.com/pouchdb/janus), which works using Mozilla Persona rather than Facebook ID, and isn't ready yet, but should be unveiled shortly